# Can TexShop be configured to open the last file I was working on?

Tags: texshop

*Solved! See below.*

When I open TS, it gives me a blank (new) doc. I would prefer that it opens with the last doc I was working on, so I can continue working.

Now I can open via "recents" but I want it to open the first doc on the recents list.

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS version are you using? Do you have your system set up to `Close windows when quitting an app` in `System Preferences->General` Pane?

Comment: 11.1 (Big Sur) 

Yes, I DO (or did) have that setting. Now it's fixed. Amazing :)